# How does Shapley obtain values in the probability space in tree classifiers?

Tags: probability, classification, odds, shapley-value

By default, the Shapley values for a tree explainer (e.g. based on xgboost) are in the log odds space (where they are additive). However, there's a functionality in the package to obtain values in the probability space through the argument model_output='probability'.

How does it work under the hood?